# PL/SQL 'select in' from a list of values whose type are different from the outer query

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-01722

I have the following tables :

```
Table1 ( Col1 : varchar2, Col2 : number, Col3 : number)
Table2 ( Col1 : number, Col2 : varchar2, Col3 : varchar2)
```

I want to run a query like this :

```
select distinct Col2 from Table1 where Col1 in 
(
   select Col1 from Table2
)
```

Table1.Col1 is of type varchar2 while Table2.Col1 is of type number. so, I need to do some casting, it seems but it fails to succeed.

The problem is that any attempts to run the query returns the following error :

```
  ORA-01722: invalid number
  01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
  *Cause:    
  *Action:
```

Table1.Col1 contains some null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT distinct col2
  FROM table1
 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT to_char(col1)
                  FROM table2)
```

should work.  Depending on the relative size of the two tables, it may be more efficient to do an `EXISTS` instead

```
SELECT distinct col2
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM table2 t2
                WHERE to_char(t2.col1) = t1.col1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error ORA-01722 is because you're trying to put `varchar2` values in an `IN` clause for an `int` column.

You've got to ensure that you're supplying int values in that `IN` clause. Give the same datatypes.